# Paw-app Receiving 401Unauthorized

Tags: rest, httprequest, paw-app

I am receiving 401 Unauthorized errors for requests I make daily on Postman and I can't figure out what the difference is or why. The only thing I've noticed in the requests I'm making and the original ones I used on Postman are the Host according to Paw is lacking the API token ID and I've tried everything I can to get it to recognize the api token in the Host portion of the request. Ex:

Postman reports host as: {api_token}:@URL/v2/
Paw reports host as: URL/v2/ yet the GET string shows the "{api_token}:" in it

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, @MarkII. Are you using HTTP Basic Auth, or OAuth? If you can, please send me the .paw file you have to support@luckymarmot.com, I'll be happy to investigate the case for you.

Comment: I have reverted back to using Postman honestly.  I would send the .paw file I was using but I don't want to reveal my API token as it would allow access to a lot of secure commands.  Thanks for finally reaching out although I will see almost a month is a long time to follow up.

Comment: I fully understand, thanks for the answer!